# Is it possible to circumvent OS security by not using the supplied System Calls?

Tags: security, assembly, operating-system, system-calls

I understand that an Operating System forces security policies on users when they use the system and filesystem via the System Calls supplied by stated OS.

Is it possible to circumvent this security by implementing your own hardware instructions instead of making use of the supplied System Call Interface of the OS? Even writing a single bit to a file where you normally have no access to would be enough.

Comment: Preventing direct hardware access is what makes privilege separation possible.  There is hardware support for isolating user-space processes from each other and the kernel.

Comment: One of the things that protects against this is the restrictions on which opcodes can be used in different rings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for simplicity, I'm considering the OS and Kernel are the same thing.

A CPU can be in different modes when executing code.
Lets say a hypothetical CPU has just two modes of execution (Supervisor and User)

- When in Supervisor mode, you are allowed to execute any instructions, and you have full access to the hardware resources.
- When in User mode, there is subset of instructions you don't have access to, such has instructions to deal with hardware or change the CPU mode. Trying to execute one of those instructions will cause the OS to be notified your application is misbehaving, and it will be terminated. This notification is done through interrupts. Also, when in User mode, you will only have access to a portion of the memory, so your application can't even touch memory it is not supposed to.

Now, the trick for this to work is that while in Supervisor Mode, you can switch to User Mode, since it's a less privileged mode, but while in User Mode, you can't go back to Supervisor Mode, since the instructions for that are not permitted anymore.
The only way to go back to Supervisor mode is through system calls, or interrupts. That enables the OS to have full control of the hardware.

A possible example how everything fits together for this hypothetical CPU:

- The CPU boots in Supervisor mode
- Since the CPU starts in Supervisor Mode, the first thing to run has access to the full system. This is the OS.
- The OS setups the hardware anyway it wants, memory protections, etc.
- The OS launches any application you want after configuring permissions for that application. Launching the application switches to User Mode.
- The application is running, and only has access to the resources the OS allowed when launching it. Any access to hardware resources need to go through System Calls.

I've only explained the flow for a single application.
As a bonus to help you understand how this fits together with several applications running, a simplified view of how preemptive multitasking works:

- In a real-world situation. The OS will setup an hardware timer before launching any applications.
- When this timer expires, it causes the CPU to interrupt whatever it was doing (e.g: Running an application), switch to Supervisor Mode and execute code at a predetermined location, which belongs to the OS and applications don't have access to.
- Since we're back into Supervisor Mode and running OS code, the OS now picks the next application to run, setups any required permissions, switches to User Mode and resumes that application.
- This timer interrupts are how you get the illusion of multitasking. The OS keeps changing between applications quickly.

The bottom line here is that unless there are bugs in the OS (or the hardware design), the only way an application can go from User Mode to Supervisor Mode is through the OS itself with a System Call.

This is the mechanism I use in my hobby project (a virtual computer)  https://github.com/ruifig/G4DevKit.

Comment: This is a great post, and made me understand the different modes of cpu executuion. Is this like the 'real' and 'protected' modes on intel processors?

Comment: @Titulum Not exactly. "Real Mode" is for backwards compatibility with CPUs earlier than the 286. x86 CPUs earlier than the 286 and had no support for any protections at all. It was a free for all. :)
"Protected Mode" offers the possibility for the OS to setup permissions for memory access and hardware resources.
An x86 cpu boots in "Real Mode" for compatibility, then some part of the OS is responsible for switching to "Protected Mode" and set the desired permissions.
Wikipedia has detailed information about those two modes.

Answer (score 2):

HW devices are connected to CPU trough bus, and CPU does use to communicate with them `in`/`out` instructions to read/write values at I/O ports (not used with current HW too much, in early age of home computers this was the common way), or a part of device memory is "mapped" into CPU address space, and CPU controls the device by writing values at defined locations in that shared memory.

All of this should be not accessible at "user level" context, where common applications are executed by OS (so application trying to write to that shared device memory would crash on illegal memory access, actually that piece of memory is usually not even mapped into user space, ie. not existing from user application point of view). Direct `in`/`out` instructions are blocked too at CPU level.

The device is controlled by the driver code, which is either run is specially configured user-level context, which has the particular ports and memory mapped (micro-kernel model, where drivers are not part of kernel, like OS MINIX). This architecture is more robust (crash in driver can't take down kernel, kernel can isolate problematic driver and restart it, or just kill it completely), but the context switches between kernel and user level are a very costly operation, so the throughput of data is hurt a bit.

Or the device drivers code runs on kernel-level (monolithic kernel model like Linux), so any vulnerability in driver code can attack the kernel directly (still not trivial, but lot more easier than trying to get tunnel out of user context trough some kernel bug). But the overall performance of I/O is better (especially with devices like graphics cards or RAID disc clusters, where the data bandwidth goes into GiBs per second). For example this is the reason why early USB drivers are such huge security risk, as they tend to be bugged a lot, so a specially crafted USB device can execute some rogue code from device in kernel-level context.

So, as Hyd already answered, under ordinary circumstances, when everything works as it should, user-level application should be not able to emit single bit outside of it's user sandbox, and suspicious behaviour outside of system calls will be either ignored, or crash the app.

If you find a way to break this rule, it's security vulnerability and those get usually patched ASAP, when the OS vendor gets notified about it.

Although some of the current problems are difficult to patch. For example "row hammering" of current DRAM chips can't be fixed at SW (OS) or CPU (configuration/firmware flash) level at all! Most of the current PC HW is vulnerable to this kind of attack.

Or in mobile world the devices are using the radiochips which are based on legacy designs, with closed source firmware developed years ago, so if you have enough resources to pay for a research on these, it's very likely you would be able to seize any particular device by fake BTS station sending malicious radio signal to the target device.

Etc... it's constant war between vendors with security researchers to patch all vulnerabilities, and hackers to find ideally zero day exploit, or at least picking up users who don't patch their devices/SW fast enough with known bugs.

Comment: The technical terms are micro-kernel vs. monolithic kernel.  You should use that to make it easier for people to google for more.  Of course, on modern Unix/Linux desktops, the graphics drivers are partially in user-space, in the X server and even in library code (libgl) run by non-root processes.  This is somewhat of a micro-kernel approach, where the kernel provides something like Linux's Direct Rendering Manager.  The untrusted user-space processes don't actually do MMIO directly, though.  I'm not sure how much checking the kernel side of DRM does on hardware commands.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for suggestions, made tiny edits (too lazy to do more, or provide some links). About DRM checking/etc: I doubt there's much going on, modern games are pushing GiB/s (getting maybe close to TiB/s order) of data, usually graphic command execution buffers in native format for particular card, so the kernel can't even decide what is valid command and what not. I think the memory bounds guarding and I/O ports is the best you can do. Inspecting the data sounds very unlikely to me (as long as you want to have common consumer grade performance, not talking about security grade sw).

Comment: So basically the answer is "Normally no, unless there's a bug in the CPU and/or in the Kernel"?

Comment: @aderchox if there would be some general "legit" way to circumvent kernel, then all the malware would be using simply that.

So yes, normally it's not possible to circumvent OS security by not using the supplied system calls (from user-space code). You shouldn't be able to read or modify any part of state which is sensitive for security, or by-pass any OS protection. If there is such a way, it's a bug and requires patching. Of course bugs happens... both HW and SW bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Not normally. If it is possible it is because of an operating system software error. If the software error is discovered it is fixed fast as it is considered to be a software vulnerability, which equals bad news.

Comment: Not entirely true. While too much work for casual problem solving, replacing file system or other drivers with "modified" versions allows to do just about anything, including to ignore security features etc. This is basically what rootkits do. They replace HAL and System drivers with "evil" replacements. Another option is to mount the hard disk with another OS and do whatever to it. Firewire also is a kind of backdoor which is sometimes exploited.

Comment: @BitTickler well, you sort of agreed with his answer. By replacing some OS file you are technically running different OS, which is not only vulnerable, but intentionally vulnerable. That's not "normally". But in properly working clean OS the user without privileges should be not able to install such rootkit/patch in the first place (ie. this could turn into lengthy pointless "opinion" discussion). Like whole OS/data disc being strongly encrypted, bootloader being signed by certificate, machine code verified by security chipset ahead of execution, firewire and USB ripped of the board. :D etc.

Comment: @Ped7g As the "supplied system calls" eventually end up calling into a loaded driver, I am tempted to answer the original question with a "Yes". Either you have a completely sealed OS where not even root/admins/system updates can change the set of installed drivers or you have an "open" system which allows for writing new third party drivers for it. The former case does not exist outside of embedded systems world. The latter is the standard case and there is no way to do both: An open, secure system.

Answer (score 0):

"System" calls execute at a higher processor level than the application: generally kernel mode (but system systems have multiple system level modes).

What you see as a "system" call is actually just a wrapper that sets up registers then triggers a Change Mode Exception of some kind (the method is system specific). The system exception hander dispatches to the appropriate system server.

You cannot just write your own function and do bad things. True, sometimes people find bugs that allow circumventing the system protections. As a general principle, you cannot access devices unless you do it through the system services.